# Using interface with enums

Tags: java, interface, enums

I am coding a mini-project of sorts about medical information, and in it, I am reading text from several data sources. All these text sources have the same *type* of information, but under slightly different labels. For example, sourceA has a section titled "adverse effects" while sourceB calls it "side effects".

I have an interface called `Reader`, and several classes (`AReader`, `BReader`, etc.) implementing this interface. Also, I have enum for each class for the section titles. For example:

```
enum ASections {
    SIDE_EFFECTS ("side effects"),
    DOSAGE       ("dosage");
    private String sectionTitle;
    private ASections(String s) { this.sectionTitle = s; }
}

enum BSections {
    SIDE_EFFECTS ("adverse effects"),
    DOSAGE       ("dosage and usage");
    private String sectionTitle;
    private BSections(String s) { this.sectionTitle = s; }
}
```

At the core of my project lies an `Orchestrator` class, which uses a `Reader` (the actual source A, B, etc. are specified by command line options). So far so good.

However, I want all the classes implementing `Reader` to also implement a method `getSectionText`, where the argument should be ASections or BSections or ...

How do I specify such a method at the interface level?

This was my first (obviously wrong) attempt:

```
public String getSectionText(Enum _section_enum);
```

The idea is that no matter which data source is specified at command line, I should be able to get the required *type* of text by fetching the appropriate section title.

Comment: The simplest thing is probably to have your _enums_ implement an interface, with a method `getSectionText` that takes whatever arguments are necessary.

Comment: I don't get what would return sectionText , why you pass a enum?

Comment: @nachokk : In my design, a class implementing the `Reader` interface has a map which maps the section title to the actual text in the section body. I want to abstract away from the exact text of the titles (because they may differ across multiple sources, e.g. "dosage", "dosage and usage", etc.). Thus, this map has enum (e.g. `ASections.DOSAGE`) as key, and the text as value. I can then do `Reader#getSectionText` to get the text.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: I didn't even know enums can implement an interface! Looking into this right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an interface that defines the method your enums must implement:

```
interface Sections {
    String getSectionTitle();
}
```

In your enums, implement that interface:

```
enum ASections implements Sections {
    SIDE_EFFECTS ("side effects"),
    DOSAGE       ("dosage");
    private String sectionTitle;
    private ASections(String s) { this.sectionTitle = s; }
    public String getSectionTitle() { return sectionTitle; }
}

enum BSections implements Sections {
    SIDE_EFFECTS ("adverse effects"),
    DOSAGE       ("dosage and usage");
    private String sectionTitle;
    private BSections(String s) { this.sectionTitle = s; }
    public String getSectionTitle() { return sectionTitle; }
}
```

In your Reader, the `getSectionText` method takes a `Sections` parameter instead of any specific enum (code against the interface, not the implementation):

```
class Reader {
    public String getSectionText(Sections sections) {
        return sections.getSectionTitle();
    }
}
```

Then you can pass either an `ASections` or a `BSections` into the reader:

```
public class Section8 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Reader reader = new Reader();
        for (ASections asection : ASections.values()) {
            System.out.println(reader.getSectionText(asection));
        }
        for (BSections bsection : BSections.values()) {
            System.out.println(reader.getSectionText(bsection));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
side effects
dosage
adverse effects
dosage and usage
```

By the way, there is an error in your enums as defined in the question. The constructor is public, however in Java the constructor of an enum must be private.

Comment: An additional, but closely related question: I have a static method in each of the enums ASections, BSections, etc. They do the exact same thing, but I can't have a static method in an interface. Is there a way to generalize this method across all the enums ASection, BSection, etc.?

Comment: Can you simply make it an instance method? Why does it have to be static? If that doesn't work, I would suggest asking it as a separate question.

Comment: Done. Putting up a link here, in case anybody is interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21789191/how-to-extend-static-methods-for-enums-implementing-an-interface

Answer (score 0):

just have the enum implement an interface, MySection, which specifies one method of `getSectionText`.