# How to extend static methods for enums implementing an interface?

Tags: java, interface, static, enums

This question is closely related to [my previous question on SO about using interface with enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21787711/using-interface-with-enums). Essentially, I have a bunch of enums that are closely related, and they all implement a common interface.

The interface is called `Sections` and the enums are called `SectionA`, `SectionB`, etc. I have other classes which have fields like `List<Sections>` and `Map<Sections, String>`. Now, to populate these fields, I would like to have access to `valueOf(String)`, i.e. I would like to be able to say something like

```
Map<Sections, String> sectionsMap = new HashMap<Sections, String>();
for (String s : someStringList) {
    try {
        sectionsMap.put(Sections.valueOf(s), someOtherFunctionReturningString(s));
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // if s doesn't match any enum
    }
}
```

I also have my own static methods in the enums `SectionA`, `SectionB`, etc. (This is because these enums all have a single `java.util.regex.Pattern` field, and my static method is a generalization of the `valueOf(String)` method based on pattern matching.)

So, my question is this:

*How can I retain access to the static methods of these enums while also having their generalization at the interface level?*

I am open to other design decisions (in fact, I am currently getting rid of the whole `enum` idea and creating classes that implement `Sections` and extend an abstract class `AbstractSection`), but I am quite curious about how others make their decisions in similar situations. I have asked this question with the hope that someone out there has better ideas than those in my head.

Comment: Interfacing an enum seems to defeat the purpose of an enum, doesn't it? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html.  From Oracle docs, "An enum type is a special data type that enables for a variable to be a set of PREDEFINED CONSTANTS."  Interfaces, by definition, are not constant.  Perhaps you don't really want enum's implementing interfaces, and should revisit your design?

Comment: The thing is, my enums are (in a way) predefined constants. How exactly? That's a lengthy detail I have provided in my previous question (the first line of this question links to it).

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to have a method that can take a string that may be part of one (which one?) of your enums, and return a value from the appropriate enum. The way it finds the enum, and the value, are based in part on a regex?

Comment: I think you may be asking the question at the wrong level of abstraction. Instead of asking how you can have a static method in the enums, you might want to ask how you can find the right enum based on a string (e.g., "side effects" vs. "adverse effects"). But you'll need to provide more information on what you're actually trying to accomplish. Enums may not be the right tool.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting this (and upvote). I have started thinking along the lines of not-enums!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override an static method.
A subclass may name a static method the same as that of the superclass, however `super` is a non-static operator.
You could have multiple methods which perform two different functions, but they would need different names.

Comment: True, but also irrelevant with respect to my question.